# Select option with value

Tags: ajax, select

How I can select option with value after ajax success? I do like this, but it doesn't work.

```
$.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/ax.php",
                        cache: false,
                        data: { action: 'show', id: pid},
                        success: function(responce){ 
                            $('div[name="qwerty"]').html(responce); 
var some_value = <?=$ads['cat2']?>;

$('#cat_2 select option[value="'+some_value +'"]').prop('selected', true);
 ...........................................................
```

P.S There is no error in console. And some_value = 10, and there is option with value 10 in select, but not selected.
P.P.S I use async:false, it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the attribute of option element. do not forget to reset this attribute on all options before selecting one

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/ax.php",
                    cache: false,
                    data: { action: 'show', id: pid},
                    success: function(responce){ 
                        $('div[name="qwerty"]').html(responce); 
 var some_value = <?=$ads['cat2']?>;

 $('#cat_2 select').val(some_value);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var val = $("select").val();
    if(val == 3) val = 1;
    else val++;
    
    $("select").val(val);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<button>Change value</button>
```

Comment: In console show: #cat_2 select option".attr is not a function

Comment: do you have jquery included on your site?

Comment: there should be closing bracket before .attr in console error. maybe typo?

Comment: jquery was included

Comment: can you post all $.ajax({...}); method? and some portion of HTML?

Comment: see the changes in my answer. there is more simple and stable solution. I added a working snippet. let me know if it helps

Comment: in your pastebin you have mismatch in the brackets. there is no ) and ; at the end of line 15 and also there should be only one } on the next line...

Comment: }); for after function

Comment: I don't understand, why do I need click for me? It doing when user enter page

Comment: code snippet is general example. you do not need click in your case.

Comment: I put  $('#cat_2 select').val(some_value);
 in code, again don't work

Comment: I put after other code  
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#cat_2 select').val('10');

  });

Comment: did you correct the brackets as I mentioned. The problem is not in the selection of value as is shown in general example snippet

Comment: It is after function brackets.I remove after function https://pastebin.com/irHmGiWu

Comment: here it is complete. customized exactly for your needs: https://pastebin.com/Mvh1YFzm

search for difference betweeen function and json syntax

Comment: #cat_2 is a select so use `#cat_2 option` selector and not `#cat_2 select option`

Comment: if you paste html when I requested you could save much time